# Eclipse build artifact with program variables

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded

I have an embedded C project in eclipse with a lot of build versions. After each build I set the name of the hex file to save in a folder. I am already using build variables for version number, but some values are defines in the code. Is there a way to use the defined values in the post build?

Another possible way is to ask for those values in a pre-build step and use them as defines and in a post build script.

Comment: Why won't you move these values out of the code and make them build variables as well?

Comment: Are you using a managed makefile project, where eclipse create makefiles? Or the build scripts are written manually?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I could do that, but the build variables change very often. How could I set them everytime I want to build a new version and use them in the output filename?

Comment: @FelipeLavratti I am using the eclipse to create the makefile, I'm not editing it directly. I am directly changing the values (defines) in a specific .h file because it is quicker (I just change it and click build) but then I have to rename the output file according to the variant I have just built. Do you think I can create a makefile with those values to automatically edit the output filename? The ideal solution was to click build, a pop up window would appear on screen, I would type the values and automatically build a variant with the correct name.